# A LIST ANAGRAM WORD PAIRS USING 2d ARRAY

Tags: c

I'm trying to do an exercise which is an anagram.

Sample input: **GARDEN DANGER WHO HOW DO ODD**

SAMPLE OUTOUT:
**A LIST OF ANAGRAM WORD PAIRS.**

**WHO : HOW**

**DANGER : GARDEN**

**this the error:**

> main.c:24:6: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion
> assigning to 'char' from 'char [10]' [-Wint-conversion]   ch = word[i];
>
> main.c:38:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
> ('char *' and 'int')   if( word[i ]== 1){
>
> main.c:39:19: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments
> [-Wformat]
> printf("%s : %s", word[i]);

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char word[5][10];
  char ch;
  int counts1[26];
  int counts2[26];
  int i = 0 , n = 5;

  printf("Input a word: ");
  
  //Read the user input
  while(i <= n){
  scanf("%s[^\n]", word[i]);
  i++;
  }
  //Count the characters
  for(i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
  counts1[i] = 0;
  counts2[i] = 0;
  }
  i = 0;
  while(word[i] != 0) {
  ch = word[i];
  if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
  ch += 32;
    }
  counts1[ch-'a']++;
  i++;
  }
  i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
  if(counts1[i] != counts2[i]) {
  return 0;
    }
  }
  //Check if Anagram or not
  if( word[i]== 1){
    printf("%s : %s", word[i]);
  }
  else{
    printf("%s is not an anagram", word[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: i) please don't shout ii) you didn't ask a question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In :

```
while(word[i] != 0) {
  ch = word[i];
```

word[i] is an array of chars (not an int) and ch is a char.

And :

```
if( word[i]== 1){
```

means nothing : you compare an array of char (word[i]) with an integer